# CSS insert break after 4th child

Tags: html, css, dom, html-lists

Currently, this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/M4aV3/) shows an unordered list with 8 list items in it.

Is there a way using only CSS (no HTML or JavaScript) to insert a break after the 4th `li` item. Something like:

```
ul li:nth-child(4n):after {
    content = '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a block-element after it: http://jsfiddle.net/M4aV3/1/

```
ul li:nth-child(4n):after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't add a break if you look at the demo

Comment: it does not work for me in chrome, even after emptying my cache.

Comment: @unludo I see (Chrome 18). That's a bug, since the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) clearly says that pseudo-elements "interact with other boxes as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element.". Adding a "real" element with display block results in the expected lay-out: http://jsfiddle.net/M4aV3/9/. **File a bug report at http://new.crbug.com/**

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a break character:

```
li:nth-child(4n):after {
   content: '\a';
   white-space: pre;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/00woyu28/